The converse to Cheyette's Ansatz
It is well known that if the HJM volatility function $\sigma(t,T) = g(t)h(T)$ where $g(t)$ is a random process then the short rate is Markovian on two state variables. One can show that this separability condition holds if and only if

$$\tag{RS}\frac{\sigma(u,T)}{\int_0^t \sigma(s,T) ds} = 
     \frac{\sigma(u,t)}{\int_0^t \sigma(s,t) ds} 
     $$
for all $u\in [0,t]$.

Ritchken and Sankarasubramanian actually state a converse in Volatility Structures of
Forward Rates and the
Dynamics of the Term
Structure
where they prove the claim above. However, they prove their result in a way that I do not understand:

This path dependence can be captured by a single statistic
common across all maturities, $T$, without imposing any additional restrictions on the initial term structure, $f(0, T)$, or on the structure for the market price of risk, $λ(t)$, providing a common “weighting scheme” exists for forward rates of all maturities. However, if a unique weighting scheme is to exists for all forward rates, it must be the case that the weighting function is independent of $T$. This in turn implies that (RS) holds.

Does anyone understand how to prove condition (RS) holds if the prices of all interest contingent claims at time $t$ are completely determined by a two-state-variable Markov process? The way I am interpreting this last claim is by saying that $P(t,T) = p(t,T,x(t),y(t))$ for some Markov process $(x(t),y(t))$ where $x(t) = r(t) - f(0,t)$, but I was not able to progress much further.
I recall reading a book or paper where condition (RS) is explained intuitively, but I cannot remember where this was done. So, a proof along of the lines of a more detailed justification of condition (RS) would also be very appreciated.
Add. I have been trying to advance of this, and this is what I have got so far.

The condition (RS) is equivalent to:
for all $t\leqslant T$ and for all $u\leqslant t$,
we have that:
$$
  \mathrm{Corr}(\sigma(u,T), \sigma(u,t)) = 1.
$$

In other words, the parametric family of processes  $T\mapsto \sigma(-,T)$ is
perfectly correlated across all times. This of course makes sense. Now writing
$$ x(t) =  \int_0^t \sigma(s,t)
        \Sigma(s,t)ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s,t)dW_s $$
suggests that $\int_0^t \sigma(s,T)dW_s$ will play an important role (like the case of Carverhill when $\sigma(t,T)$ is deterministic) and indeed the function $\Lambda(t,T) = \int_0^t \sigma(u,T)du$ is what the authors say is ''independent of $T$'', I think.
So I suspect one has to use some kind of Itō isometry (maybe conditional) to say something about $\Lambda(t,T)$ that implies (RS) when $(x(t), y(t))$ is Markov where $y(t) = \int_0^t \eta(s)^2 ds$ where $\eta(t) = \sigma(t,t)$.
